# Thunderbird authenticating with dovecot fails in 0 secs without username

Tags: windows-10, fedora, thunderbird, authentication, dovecot

I have set up Dovecot with effective configuration (with `dovecot -n`)

```
# 2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 5.2.15-200.fc30.x86_64 x86_64 Fedora release 30 (Thirty)
# Hostname: <my hostname>
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
listen = 10.168.0.9,<my external IP>
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
    inbox = yes
    location =
    mailbox Drafts {
        special_use = \Drafts
    }
    mailbox Junk {
        special_use = \Junk
    }
    mailbox Sent {
        special_use = \Sent
    }
    mailbox "Sent Messages" {
        special_use = \Sent
    }
    mailbox Trash {
        special_use = \Trash
    }
    prefix =
}
passdb {
    driver = pam
}
protocols = imap
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/<my hostname>/cert.pem
ssl_cipher_list = PROFILE=SYSTEM
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
    args = blocking=no
    driver = passwd
}
verbose_ssl = yes
```

I am trying to connect to this with Thunderbird 60.9.0 but no matter whether I use port 143 or 993, the authentication does not take place. `journalctl -efu dovecot.service` output:

```
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=2668)
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write key exchange
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server done
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client key exchange
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read change cipher spec
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read finished
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write finished
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=10.168.0.53, lip=<myhostextip>, TLS, session=<OvtgaBWT5iUKqAA1>
Sep 21 21:43:58 <myhostname> dovecot[31705]: imap-login: Debug: SSL alert: close notify
```

The error appears to be indicated on the second-to-last row: "no auth attempts in 0 secs."
[Problems with connecting Thunderbird client to dovecot installed on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/286638/problems-with-connecting-thunderbird-client-to-dovecot-installed-on-ubuntu) indicated a potential problem with certificate exceptions. I deleted the certificate stored in Thunderbird (Windows version) and then obtained it again under Manage Certificates and added the security exception. This did not help. In addition, the log file above implies that the certificate dialog went OK.

If I add `cram-md5` as a supported authentication mechanism, I will additionally get `auth: Fatal: CRAM-MD5 mechanism can't be supported with given passdbs` in the log.

What am I not seeing or what am I misunderstanding or doing wrong? How do I make it work?

Edit: Tested with Thunderbird x64, which would use a completely fresh profile. Does not work. Tried upgrading Thunderbird from 60 to 68. Does not help. Used Mozilla's log feature to log authentication and IMAP traffic. Nothing gets logged in authentication and nothing about the dovecot service in IMAP traffic.

Comment: What happens if try to connect with something else than Thunderbird?

Comment: When I try to connect with Samsung Galaxy S8's default e-mail application, the authentication succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the certificates. **While the certificate is trusted, it was assigned to the publicly used name of the server. I was accessing the server from the internal network with the internal IP address.** Therefore, Thunderbird refused to communicate with the server.

Confirming a security exception did not help in this matter, before setting connection security to None and Authentication method to Normal password, which allowed me to exit the initial account setup configuration window. After that, changing the account settings back to SSL/TLS and Normal password made Thunderbird prompt me for a security exception, which I confirmed, and now it works.

Comment: Same problem, but the trick didn't solve for me.